# AngularJS factory with promises not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs factory and I do a $http.get request to fetch JSON data and compare. I try to return out the filtered list but it doesnt seems to work.

```js
    app.service('ScopeService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

var service = {};

  var permsList = [],
    codeMapping;
    
  var perms = {
    "admin": true,
    "dev": true,
    "qa": true,
    "audit": false,
    "general": true,
    "grp1": false,
    "grp2": false,
    "grp3": false,
    "grp4": false,
    "grp5": true,
    "env": "DEV",
    "version": "1.6.3"
  }

function mapping() {

    $http.get('./utils/codeMapping.json').then(function (response) {
codeMapping = response.data.codeMapping;

function findBU(BG) {
    return _.find(codeMapping, ['id', Name]).number
}

if (perms.grp1) {
    permsList = permsList.concat(findBU('A'));
}

if (perms.grp2) {
    permsList = permsList.concat(findBU('B'));
}

if (perms.grp3) {
    permsList = permsList.concat(findBU('C'));
}

if (perms.grp4) {
    permsList = permsList.concat(findBU('D'));
}

if (perms.grp5) {
    permsList = permsList.concat(findBU('E'));
}

if (perms.audit) {
    permsList = [];
}

$q.resolve(permsList);
});
}

service.getMapping = function() {
    return mapping();
};

service.getMapping().then(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
})
return service;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

So "outside" gives me the data I want but its not working inside the getMapping function.

I think its because of a timing mismatch as service is being called with an empty object before the value of getMapping is being added.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what code you provided its a little difficult to tell how you're using this. However, It appears you are not returning a promise, you're returning an array object. Also, I'm not sure why you are chaining another then in on your get request. Try something like this...

Check out a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/riegersn/rnd4ujfd/12/

```
app.service('ScopeService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

    var service = {};

    var permsList = [],
        codeMapping;

    var perms = {
        "admin": true,
        "dev": true,
        "qa": true,
        "audit": false,
        "general": true,
        "grp1": false,
        "grp2": false,
        "grp3": false,
        "grp4": false,
        "grp5": true,
        "env": "DEV",
        "version": "1.6.3"
    }

    service.getMappings = function() {
        return $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1').then(function(response) {
            /* manipulate your data */
            permsList.push('some data!');
            console.log(permsList);
            return $q.resolve(permsList);
        });
    }

    return service;
}]);
```

Comment: Hi I tried that. Removed the second .then() and did what you had mentioned. It says that service.getMapping() is not a function.

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem is with the code you've provided.

Comment: So, i have defined service as an empty object in the top. When I create a function called service.getMapping and try to return the value of mapping() inside the function, it returns undefined as it is invoked immediately. Does a promise waterfall work?

Comment: into my factory at the top. I can refactor my code even more.Edited my code to my current implementation.

Comment: looks like you removed your getMapping function from the service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166049/discussion-between-a2441918-and-shwnrgr).

Comment: Updated my code again. Says cannot read property then of undefined

Comment: You're not returning anything in your mapping function. See me updated example